Reducing the size of an incremental backup by manually deleting files within the archive
I recently performed an extensive restructuring of my personal data directory to improve its organization. After backup, my incremental backup of this restructured directory doubled in size, from 0.6 TB to 1.2 TB, despite no increase in the size of the data. I assume the incremental backup doubled in size because the backup software did not identify that directories had been renamed, in addition to the backup software not performing data de-duplication. The backup software is Synology Hyperbackup version 3 on DSM version 7. The backup is incremental with 256 versions saved in a rotation that spans approximately the past ten years.
I want to reduce the size of the backup. Removing duplicate and other unnecessary files will decrease the size of the backup to about 1/5 the current size.
What is the best way to reduce the size of an incremental backup? Ideally I would use the backup software to de-duplicate and prune data. However, I do not see a way to use Hyperbackup to remove duplicates from my archive.1 Furthermore, Hyperbackup does not support deletion of files or directories within an incremental backup archive.
Also, I need to preserve a subset of versions spanning the history of the backup. Consequently I cannot simply restore the most recent version and discard earlier versions.
I am considering the following strategy of manually copying a subset of versions from the backup history then performing file level de-duplication and manual pruning of the copied data:

Manually copy a set of approximately ten versions of the data from the incremental backup history, regularly spaced chronologically, beginning with the earliest version and ending with the most recent. (For example: 10-years-ago/my-data, 9-years-ago/my-data, ... current-day/my-data .)
Perform file level de-duplication on the set of versions copied in step 1. (I plan to use Czkawka to perform the de-duplication.)
Manually remove any other unnecessary non-duplicate files from the set of versions copied in step 1.
Start a new backup using the de-duplicated and pruned versions of the data.

Are there potential problems with the proposed strategy? My primary concern is human error due to the amount manual labor involved. Is there a better (faster, more automated, etc.) strategy to safely reduce the size of this incremental backup while retaining a subset of versions spanning the history of the backup?
1 Although recent versions of Synology Hyperbackup support de-duplication, this does not appear to be an option with my existing incremental backup archive. Perhaps my Hyperbackup archive was created by an earlier version of the software before de-duplication was implemented.
